# Dynamic Fragment recreation and setRetainInstance(true)

Tags: android, dynamic, android-fragments

I don't completely understand how an activity and its fragments are recreated.

Imagine the following scenario: you have a database, activity reading this `DB` and a fragment, which will be created, if the activity's query to `DB` has some data. If `DB` is empty a fragment's `onCreateView` will cause an exception.

Now imagine we moved the app to background for a while and activity was destroyed. Moreover, the `DB` changes and gets empty.

How this structure will be recreated? Activity starts and understands that fragment is not needed, so everything is ok, or the fragment is recreated then anyway, because it already was created? Does `setRetainInstance(true/false)` has an influence on this process?

Making it more complex: we have several fragments, where one decides, if the other should be created or not in a similar way. What is the order of fragments recreation? Is it some kind of a race condition or the order is predefined?

Finally, how can we prevent or control the recreation of a fragment?  I guess I have a situation, when sometimes a fragment is recreated not in right time. How such an architecture could be fixed? Simply removing fragment with `onStop()`?

Comment: A quick note: you shouldn't ever call `onStop()` yourself-- this will be called by the Android runtime. You can call `finish()` instead

Comment: @user184994, Yeah, it's clear. I can just move `mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragment).commit()` to `OnStop()` and the fragment will automatically be removed in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't completely understand how an activity and its fragments are
>   recreated.

First of all it's very important to have very clear how the lifecycle of the Activity/Fragments works in Android. Here I link what is IMHO the most complete diagram on the subject (even more than the official one):

http://staticfree.info/~steve/complete_android_fragment_lifecycle.svg

> Imagine the following scenario: you have a database, activity reading
>   this DB and a fragment, which will be created, if the activity's query
>   to DB has some data. If DB is empty a fragment's onCreateView will
>   cause an exception. Now imagine we moved the app to background for a
>   while and activity was destroyed. Moreover, the DB changes and gets
>   empty.

This kind of operation, like reading or writing to a DB (or connecting to a web service or more) are considered I/O and should get managed properly in background. I don't know concrete details in your case but in your example, you can use a CursorLoader. Android docs says the following:

> A loader that queries the ContentResolver and returns a Cursor. This
>   class implements the Loader protocol in a standard way for querying
>   cursors, building on AsyncTaskLoader to perform the cursor query on a
>   background thread so that it does not block the application's UI.

Moreover

> If DB is empty a fragment's onCreateView will cause an exception.

If a DB is empty the fragment should not cause an exception (any), if you're using, for example, a CursorLoader it will eventually get a Cursor with 0 entries. Later on (and again this depends on your implementation), if you update your database you can do a new CursorLoader petition to get a refreshed Cursor with the new data (the same applies if you rotate your device).

Two good tutorials that talks more in deep about CursorLoader are [How to use Loarders](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/) written by **Wolfram Rittmeyer** and [Life before Loaders](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) by **Alex Lockwood**

> Activity starts and understands that fragment is not needed, so
>   everything is ok, or the fragment is recreated then anyway, because it
>   already was created? Does setRetainInstance(true/false) has an
>   influence on this process?

An activity is a "dumb" component, by itself it does not know nothing about what a fragment is (well that's not quite true because the implementation of the activity knows about fragments). But for good sake it really depends on what you try to do. If you have a fragment in your activity it will be eventually recreated. Two classes you have to keep an eye to understand how this work is:

- [FragmentActivity.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java)
- [FragmentManagerImpl.java](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java/?v=source)

> Finally, how can we prevent or control the recreation of a fragment? I
>   guess I have a situation, when sometimes a fragment is recreated not
>   in right time. How such an architecture could be fixed? Simply
>   removing fragment with onStop()?

Never mess with lifecycle events by yourself, this is managed properly by the android runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I got it. You say Activity is dumb, however, I understood that it is activity's duty to manage its fragments properly and strictly control, when the specific fragment is to be created, recreated and so on.

Comment: Yes, Android manages fragment restoration (more preciscely `FragmentManagerImpl.java`), events like onActivityResult get forwarded to the fragment and more automatically (you can see it in the code of `FragmentActivity.java`) but when you put fragments in the activity. If there are not fragments in your code it does nothing related with it. I'm thinking about a sample project with does things with fragments (beyond the basics but I don't remember one exactly right now :/).

Comment: The only example I have in mind is the source code of ioSched 2013 but it is a complete application… but it does uses a lot of fragments, cursorloaders and more! Link: https://github.com/skyisle/iosched

Answer (score 0):

The fragment's lifecycle is tied to that of the Activity. From the Android docs:

> *Stopped*
>
> The fragment is not visible. Either the host activity has been stopped or the fragment has been removed from the activity but added to the back stack. A stopped fragment is still alive (all state and member information is retained by the system). However, it is no longer visible to the user and will be killed if the activity is killed.

When the Activity is destroyed, it will call the `onCreate()` method to recreate the Activity. This means that if the underlying database has changed, the Activity can decide not to launch the fragment.

You can read more about the Fragment lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle), and the Activity lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html).

Comment: Does that mean, when setRetainInstance(true) is used, the fragment will be recreated only if the Activity has a desire to use that fragment?

Comment: If you set`setRetainInstance` to true, the fragment won't actually be destroyed, even if the Activity is. It won't need to be re-created because it will still exist